# How can I optimize the calculation over this function in numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, kernel-density

I want to implement the following problem in numpy and here is my code.

I've tried the following numpy code for this problem with one for loop. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way of doing this calculation? I really appreciate that!

```
k, d = X.shape
m = Y.shape[0]

c1 = 2.0*sigma**2
c2 = 0.5*np.log(np.pi*c1)
c3 = np.log(1.0/k)

L_B = np.zeros((m,))
for i in xrange(m):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print i
    L_B[i] = np.log(np.sum(np.exp(np.sum(-np.divide(
                np.power(X-Y[i,:],2), c1)-c2,1)+c3)))

print np.mean(L_B)
```

I've thought of `np.expand_dims(X, 2).repeat(Y.shape[0], 2)-Y` by creating a 3D tensor therefore the following calculation can be done by broadcasting, but that would waste a lot of memory when `m` is large.

I also believe that the `np.einsum()` utilizes nothing but the for loop so might not be that efficient, correct me if I am wrong.

Any thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Optimization Stage #1**

My first level of optimizations using a direct translation of the loopy code to a `broadcasting` based one upon introducing a new axis and as such not so memory efficient one, as listed below -

```
p1 = (-((X[:,None] - Y)**2)/c1)-c2
p11 = p1.sum(2)
p2 = np.exp(p11+c3)
out = np.log(p2.sum(0)).mean()
```

**Optimization Stage #2**

Bringing in few optimizations keeping in mind that we intend to separate out the operations on the constants, I ended up with the following -

```
c10 = -c1
c20 = X.shape[1]*c2

subs = (X[:,None] - Y)**2
p00 = subs.sum(2)
p10 = p00/c10
p11 = p10-c20
p2 = np.exp(p11+c3)
out = np.log(p2.sum(0)).mean()
```

**Optimization Stage #3**

Going further with it and and seeing the places where the operations could be optimized, I ended up using [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to replace the heavy-weight work of the squaring and `sum-reduction`. This should be pretty memory efficient and gave us the final implementation, as shown below -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# Setup constants
c10 = -c1
c20 = X.shape[1]*c2
c30 = c20-c3
c40 = np.exp(c30)
c50 = np.log(c40)

# Get stagewise operations corresponding to loopy ones
p1 = cdist(X, Y, 'sqeuclidean')
p2 = np.exp(p1/c10).sum(0)
out = np.log(p2).mean() - c50
```

---

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def loopy_app(X, Y, sigma):
    k, d = X.shape
    m = Y.shape[0]

    c1 = 2.0*sigma**2
    c2 = 0.5*np.log(np.pi*c1)
    c3 = np.log(1.0/k)

    L_B = np.zeros((m,))
    for i in xrange(m):
        L_B[i] = np.log(np.sum(np.exp(np.sum(-np.divide(
                    np.power(X-Y[i,:],2), c1)-c2,1)+c3)))

    return np.mean(L_B)

def vectorized_app(X, Y, sigma):
    # Setup constants
    k, d = D_A.shape
    c1 = 2.0*sigma**2
    c2 = 0.5*np.log(np.pi*c1)
    c3 = np.log(1.0/k)

    c10 = -c1
    c20 = X.shape[1]*c2
    c30 = c20-c3
    c40 = np.exp(c30)
    c50 = np.log(c40)

    # Get stagewise operations corresponding to loopy ones
    p1 = cdist(X, Y, 'sqeuclidean')
    p2 = np.exp(p1/c10).sum(0)
    out = np.log(p2).mean() - c50
    return out
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [294]: # Setup inputs with m(=D_B.shape[0]) being a large number
     ...: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,10))
     ...: Y = np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,10))
     ...: sigma = 2.34
     ...: 

In [295]: np.allclose(loopy_app(X, Y, sigma),vectorized_app(X, Y, sigma))
Out[295]: True

In [296]: %timeit loopy_app(X, Y, sigma)
1 loops, best of 3: 225 ms per loop

In [297]: %timeit vectorized_app(X, Y, sigma)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop

In [298]: # Setup inputs with m(=Y.shape[0]) being a much large number
     ...: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,10))
     ...: Y = np.random.randint(0,9,(100000,10))
     ...: sigma = 2.34
     ...: 

In [299]: np.allclose(loopy_app(X, Y, sigma),vectorized_app(X, Y, sigma))
Out[299]: True

In [300]: %timeit loopy_app(X, Y, sigma)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.27 s per loop

In [301]: %timeit vectorized_app(X, Y, sigma)
1 loops, best of 3: 243 ms per loop
```

Around **`10x`** speedup there!

Comment: Amazing! More than 10x!

Comment: @xxx222 What speedup are you getting on your actual dataset?

Comment: Around 20x or so, because I have a very large dataset so calculating the distance matrix becomes hard.